# Retrieve parent child checked values as comma separated

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am developing application to select the role based menu. In that, I have parent-child check box and I want to retrieve checkbox checked value as **1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3** but current jQuery return as **1, 1, 2, 2, 3**.

I have googled many things and implemented few too but there is no idea for parent child checked values selection.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Upload
    <ul>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Large </li>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Small </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Move</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="3">Producs</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="5">User</li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.check_box:checked').map(function () { return this.value; }).get().join(',')
```

**Checkbox Selection**

[image]

**Current output**

> 1, 1, 2, 2, 3

**Expected Output**

> 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3

Comment: I'd set the `input` values appropriately, so that there's no need to decipher anything, or write buggy data collection scripts.  `value="1"`, `value="1.2"`, etc.

Comment: I've removed my original comments, but to add to @DBro's comment, if you can't change the `value`, you could add data-attributes (`data-value="1"`, `data-value="1.2"`) and use them instead

Comment: because of you have a multi-level structure, but map get ALL OF ITEMS without nesting levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the ability to add data attributes, it's fairly simple...

```js
$(function(){
  $(".check_box").on("click", function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log($(".check_box:checked").map((i,el) => $(el).data("value")).get().join(","));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1" data-value="1">Upload
    <ul>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1" data-value="1.1">Large </li>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2" data-value="1.2">Small </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2" data-value="2">Move</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="3" data-value="3">Producs</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="5" data-value="5">User</li>
</ul>
```

---

However, if you must stick with the HTML you've got... it's not exactly elegant (in fact it's anything *but* elegant), but the following will do what you need it to...

It also has the advantage that you can multiple nest the `<ul>` and it will result in `1.1.1` etc.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".check_box").on("click", function() {
    var values = buildValues($("#root"),"");
    if (values.length > 0) {
      values = values.substring(0, values.length - 1);
    }
    console.clear();
    console.log(values);
  });
});

function buildValues($ul,parentValue) {
  var values = "";
  // Go though each listitem
  $ul.children("li").each(function() {
    // Get the checkbox and the value
    var $chk = $(this).children().first();
    var value = $chk.val().toString();
    // If the checkbox is ticked, add the value to the string
    if ($chk.is(":checked")){
      values += parentValue + value + ",";
    }
    // See if there is another element
    var $subUL = $chk.next();
    if ($subUL.length > 0) {
      // Recurse using the current value
      values += buildValues($subUL, value + ".");
    }
  });
  return values;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="root">
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Upload
    <ul>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Large </li>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Small </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Move</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="3">Producs</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="5">User</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: heads up, your function using data attributes isn't working right. The log shows all values changing to whatever is number is the most recently selected.

Comment: Yep, just noticed myself - have already fixed - but thanks for reporting :-)

Comment: @freefaller thanks for your wonderful answer. Also i need bind the values to checkbox. Can you please guid me?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "I need bind the values to checkbox"